# Keep Google collob running even after internet connection is lost

Tags: google-colaboratory

Is there a way to keep google collab running even after losing internet connection for some time?

Comment: Maybe you did not find [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49062628/does-google-colab-stay-connected-when-i-close-my-browser) yet? The cell apparently keeps running, but its output will not be stored in the notebook (local saves however do get stored).

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know and I found in the online articles Colab doesn't support running without an internet connection.