# How do I close and reopen running notebook in Google's Colab?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory

Using Jupyter notebook locally, I occasionally start computations and close tab and  will come back to it later when computations are done. I wonder if this same is possible with Google Colab. As far as I understand currently, if I close Google Colab notebook, I loose everything.

Comment: See this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49080571).