# How to train and save model on google colab that would take days to finish training?

Tags: deep-learning, cloud, google-colaboratory

I'm training a natural language model on google colab, and from current progress of training, I can see that my model will take at least 1 to 2 days to finish the training. After training I also want to save the model in my google drive. So, basically there issues here is.

(1) I'm using internet of my university, which logs me out after nearly 90 minutes. So, I want my model to continue training on cloud, even after my college wifi logs me out.

I looked [this](https://youtu.be/RpQaAbMmqkA) video on YouTube which writes a script to click the connect button periodically after some time, but it won't help me since my university wifi will disconnect the internet after 90 mins, I'll have to login again to reconnect.

I also looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49062628/does-google-colab-stay-connected-when-i-close-my-browser) similar question on stackoverflow, but I'm not able to understand whether that will be able to solve my issue. I want to keep my model training once internet is not there, and also save my model to my google drive once the training is complete. I can add a script in my code to save the model, but how can I be sure that my model is running continuously on cloud? That question somewhat looks like keeping the session connected after closing the browser.

Answer (score 0):

Base on my experiment, your model training will still run even when your internet is down, but not so long after you disconnect, the training will stop. I think you can save your model every a few epochs so you can continue training from that point later.

And about "keeping the session connected after closing the browser", it's safe to close your browser, just re-open it and everything is still there.