# Colab: How to disconnect from session without closing the tab?

Tags: google-colaboratory

**Some background**

My computer fan goes crazy when I am using Google Colab, it definitely uses local resources somehow. I am running very long processes (over 4 hours). Yesterday, it occurred to me that I was disconnected, I thought my session had crashed since I stoped receiving the status updates of my task's progress bar. But then after clicking on `Connect to a hosted runtime` I was able to reconnect to that session and just interact with it fine. Given that Google Colab uses some of my local resource, I looking for a way to put the client application on halt for a little bit.

**Question**

How to manually disconnect from my remote session without crashing/terminating it? Is that even possible?

---

Note:

There is an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49080571/2313889) for [Does Google Colab stay connected when I close my browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49062628/2313889) that says

> The current cell will continue executing once you close your browser, but the outputs will not end up in the notebook in Drive.

I would be fine if I am able to leave the session running remotely but not being able to access the outputs on the notebook, given that I save the result on google drive when the process is done. So, not been able to see the output on the notebook would not be an issue for me.